# Is it a removable singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity-theory

In the function:

$$
f(z)=2iz\frac{(1-z^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1-2z^{2}} \qquad \qquad (z \in \mathbb{Z}) \,\, ,
$$

There is a singularity at the point $z=\pm \sqrt{1/2}$. Is that a removable singularity? How to know this?

Comment: there are also some sort of singularities at $z = \pm 1$ (it is not holomorphic there)

Answer (score 3):

> Is that a removable singularity? How to know this?

No, this is not a removable singularity : the numerator **does not vanish** at $z=1/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

No, numerator gives zeros of $0,\pm 1$ and denominator gives zeros of $\displaystyle \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ which are the poles of $f(z)$. Unlike $\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{x}$, both the numerator and denominator have the same "zero", which is $z=0$, of order one.

Comment: When  is a singularity removable?

Comment: Let $f(z)=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$, where $P^{(k)}(a)=Q^{(k)}(a)=0$, $\forall k=0,\ldots, n$ but $Q^{(n+1)}(a) \neq 0$, then $z=a$ is a removable singularity.